# Can I load .kv file multiple times when the app is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have two different `.kv` files:

1. file defining main interface --> `PriceTrackerUI.kv`
2. file defining popup window --> `PopupWindow.kv`

I want to "refresh" content of popup window, every time I close it.

In `PopupWindow.kv` the program opens an image by loading file which already exists in a directory. This file is overwritten every time in latter stage of running the app. The problem is, `.kv` files are loaded at the sheer initialisation of the program and not getting loaded again later. And as it makes sense with the main UI window, it doesn't with popup, which content changes with every click of the button in main UI window

Below is a minimal code

`PopupWindow.kv`:

```
<PopupWindow>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1, .9
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        cols: 2

    AsyncImage:
        source: root.daily  # loading image stored under that variable
        allow_stretch: True
        size_hint: .9, 1
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'center_y': .5}

   (...)
```

`PriceTrackerUI`:

```
<SearchPerformer>
GridLayout:
    size: root.size
    cols: 2
    rows: 3

  (...)

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Search'
            size_hint: .5, .4
            pos_hint: {"x": .75, "top": .9}
            border: 20, 20, 20, 20
            on_press: root.input_grabber(root.dt)
            on_release: root.clear()
            on_release: root.hit_enter()
```

`main.py`:

```
import UI


UI.PriceTrackerUIApp().run()
```

`UI.py`:

```
import kivy
import database
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

kivy.require('1.11.1')


user_input = []

Builder.load_file('PopupWindow.kv')


class PopupWindow(BoxLayout):
    daily = StringProperty('./daily.png')


def popup_show():
    pop = PopupWindow()

    pop_win = Popup(title="Analysis", content=pop, size_hint=(.9, .9))
    pop_win.open()


class SearchPerformer(BoxLayout):
    dt = database

    def hit_enter(self):
        popup_show()

    def input_grabber(self, database):
        specs = [self.ids.crmk.text, self.ids.crmd.text, self.ids.cryr.text, self.ids.crft.text]
        (...)
        user_input.extend(specs)
        database.add_to_database()
        database.query_database()
        database.run_plot() # daily.png image gets updated after running that method


class PriceTrackerUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SearchPerformer()
```

Comment: Reloading the `kv` only makes sense if you are changing what is in the `kv`. What would you be changing in `PopupWindow.kv`? If you don't make any change, then reloading will have no effect.

Comment: The sheer content of that `kv` file won't be changed, just only the image `daily.png` is supposed to change, as it will be overwritten every time.

Comment: The thing is `PopupWindow.kv` run before `daily.png` will change. File `PopupWindow.kv` should be loaded after running `database.run_plot` in `input_grabber` method. That’s why I was trying to load it explicitly all over again in some part of code…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to open a new `Popup` after changing the `daily.png` file, your current code should reflect the changed `daily.png` in the new `Popup`. Reloading the `kv` will not affect that.

If you are trying to update the `AsyncImage` in an already open `Popup`, then reloading the `kv` will have no effect. In that case, you just need to call the `reload()` method of the `AsnycImage`. Of course, that means that you must retain a reference to the `PopupWindow` and probably add an `id` to the `AsyncImage`. So, to add an `id`, a slightly modified `kv`:

```
<PopupWindow>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1, .9
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        cols: 2

    AsyncImage:
        id: img   # id to be used for calling reload()
        source: root.daily  # loading image stored under that variable
        allow_stretch: True
        size_hint: .9, 1
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'center_y': .5}
```

And use that in your code (along with some small modifications):

```
def popup_show():
    pop = PopupWindow()

    pop_win = Popup(title="Analysis", content=pop, size_hint=(.9, .9))
    pop_win.open()
    return pop   # save a reference to the `PopupWindow`


class SearchPerformer(BoxLayout):
    dt = database
    pop = ObjectProperty(None)

    def hit_enter(self):
        self.pop = popup_show()  # retain reference to `PopupWindow`

    def input_grabber(self, database):
        specs = [self.ids.crmk.text, self.ids.crmd.text, self.ids.cryr.text, self.ids.crft.text]
        (...)
        user_input.extend(specs)
        database.add_to_database()
        database.query_database()
        database.run_plot() # daily.png image gets updated after running that method
        if self.pop is not None:
            self.pop.ids.img.reload()   # reload the updated daily.png
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can load a kv file at any point using `Builder.load_file` or `Builder.load_string`. When you instantiate a widget, any previously-loaded rules are applied.

Comment: The thing I want to do is to load `PopupWindow.kv` just after executing `database.run_plot` from `imput_grabber` method to run new overwritten `daily.png` file. If I will not do that, in `PopupWindow.kv` is loaded image with old content.

Comment: I am not sure if loading it explicitly by `Builder.load_file` or `Builder.load_string` will get me my desirable outcome. If so, in what part of code would you put it ?

Comment: If you want to load PopupWindow.kv kust after executing database.run_plot...then put `Builder.load_file("PopupWindow.kv")` just after executing database.run_plot. But I'm not really clear what your problem is and I'm suspicious this may be an XY problem, please post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the issue (and try to make it genuinely minimal, cut out _everything_ not necessary to demonstrate the problem).